# Require identifiers for SFSE users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

I'm happy that we have so many people posting, but I'd like to turn this into a real community. There are some people with aliases that are non-name-related, but who have profiles with their real name (e.g. @[metadaddy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) - though it's in his description) and some people who have a name as an alias and real name info (me).

There are also users who have the generic "user####" alias, and I wonder if that is - on the aggregate - lowering the quality of the exchange. (Exceptions, obviously, include @[user320](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/320/user320) and @[sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox), though I am curious as to their real identities.) (I know I have an incorrect age on here, so before crying hypocrite, please know that I think it's a ridiculous thing to put on a professional profile.)

On the whole, I see questions from the anonymous users who are writing fragmented, hardly intelligible posts, generally demanding code without demonstrating having worked towards something or showing any history of even using Google (or even Bing) to find an answer.

**Proposal:** If possible, require Firstname and Lastname. Sure, people can spoof that, but I think it would help things. I'd even go so far as to find a way to note users who do some sort of verified identity.

Comment: On a light side I wanna know who's that Pokemon #sfdcfox ( his identity is only know to a few or may be not). On a serious note, I am totally fine getting answers resolved than identity being revealed:). The one frustrating part is when you leave comments asking for more info and they don't turn back just because they have solved it or moved on from the question. This seriously affects the answered % of the community. Even if naming was made compulsory the users cannot be forced to mark the answers solved/reply. It is only an etiquette and would be nice if we all had have our identities known.

Comment: @rao You too can discover who #sfdcfox is. Have a careful read of his profile page. I don't think it is any big secret.

Answer (score 16):

As a stackexchange site we're limited in terms of customization and having special rules "enforced" on the community. Requiring real names would probably also go against the overall "stackexchange philosophy", where even anonymous users can contribute.

While I agree with your observations, I also do not think named users would truly be a solutions. Even on the Success community, and on LinkedIn for instance, where users are identified by their actual name, you see these sort low quality questions or never returning OP's. (But less for code, as that's less traditional on those platforms).

It is the shared responsibility of the community, all of us, to improve the quality of both questions, answers [and to engage others to become part of the community aspect of this site](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/536/119) .  Also: [You may or should edit where you think you can improve](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/606/119).

Comment: +1. Your answer completely sums up my thoughts.

Comment: I think the voting mechanisms of Stackexchange are a far more powerful mechanism for managing quality than any real name verification.  As LinkedIn proves people are more than willing to post the most 'interesting' questions under their own names